# Shared VPC: how to setup access to VMs in host project from service projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I successfully shared a subnetwork between two projects and was able to launch a VM on the shared subnetwork from the service project.

What should I do to be able to access that VM from other VMs of the service project (different subnetwork than the shared one)?

I tried to add a firewall rule to the host project, allowing all traffic from a service account of other project and used the service account from the service project VMs, it didn't help...

Comment: "different subnetwork than the shared one" this is the key, are the subnetworks in the same shared VPC network or in different VPC networks? If they are in different networks, that is not shared VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMs in different projects (including host and service projects) of the same shared VPC should be able to communicate with each other via internal IP addresses by default. See [Shared VPC and internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shared-vpc/#shared_vpc_and_internal_dns)

> VM instances in a shared VPC host network can communicate with each other via internal IP addresses even if the instances were created by different service projects. Instances can also reach each other via fully qualified internal DNS names in the format [HOST_NAME].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal.

Comment: I already saw that comment, DNS doesn't resolve this way across my host and service projects... (it does for the same project). so something is definitely different...

I launched an instance in the service project with two network interfaces, one on the shared VPC and the other on the service project and was able to access instances in both networks. but this kind of setup isn't what i'm looking for

Comment: Could you add the details about your VM's 2 interfaces and how you test the communication.

Comment: that VM was created in the service project on the shared subnetwork, eth0 is of the shared subnwork, eth1 is of the service project. I connected via SSH and was able to access instances in both subnetworks. for now, I added network peering to both projects and bunch of firewall rules which solved the issue but i'm not sure its the solution i'm happiest with...

Comment: So, this is not merely a shared VPC problem, it is about peered VPCs, you want VMs to communicate across peered VPCs?

Comment: no, I used peered VPC for now because I couldn't get it to work

Comment: So, you actually have 2 VPC networks, one is the shared VPC in host project, one is in the service project, you want to make VMs in the 2 VPC networks communicate with each other? That is not the problem shared VPC meant to solve.